# lein test doesn't return exit code properly with clojure hystrix

Tags: clojure, hystrix

I am trying this out

```
(defn square-function [input]
  (is (= 0 1))
  (* input input))

(hystrix/defcommand square
  {}
  [data]
  (square-function data))

(deftest testing-square
  (is (= 16 (square 4))))
```

If I run lein test, the test fails but returns an exit code 0.

Not sure how hystrix is affecting lein's exit code.

Comment: Why do you have another `(is (= 0 1))` in your square function?  Is this function defined inside the tests, so there actually is `is` defined?

Comment: basically I was trying to assert on the input that is going in the square function.

but it seems even though the `(is (= 0 1))` assertion fails, lein returns an exit code 0